# How to get email address of contact using Microsoft's EWS API 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get email addresses of all contacts in my default contact folder.So far I have been successfull using following code;

```
var contactsfolder = ContactsFolder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Contacts,
                    new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, FolderSchema.TotalCount));
 var view = new ItemView(contactsfolder.TotalCount)
  {
      PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ContactSchema.DisplayName, ContactSchema.EmailAddress1)
  };
 var contactItems = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, view);
```

Sometimes I get email that is not a valid SMTP e-mail address.

```
/o=WWE/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=e20105f2e8434d9ea58efc56e8b5a173-John Cena
```

My question is how can I get valid email address from above stuff (common name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FindItems will generally return the native address (eg the EX Address) for performance reason. If you make a GetItem request (eg Load or LoadProperitesfromitems) on the same item then Exchange should convert the EX address to a SMTP address for you.

Otherwise you can also do it yourself using ResolveName https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn645423(v=exchg.150).aspx on the EX address (as long as that is listed in the GAL)

The one exception is if you have a contact for a user that was deleted from the Global Address list because they have left the company and their mailbox has been deleted. Because only the EX address is stored in a Contact added from the GAL it won't be able to translate this back into the SMTP address.

Comment: Thank you @Glen I resolved it by using ResolveName  method, although It is not that effective when there are multiple persons with the same name in global address book.

Comment: Was very helpful! Same thing happened with the java ews api, but calling `load()` on the contact object did in fact convert it to an SMTP email